# Play Controllers functional test with PlaySpec

Tags: scala, testing, playframework

I'm using Play Scala 2.5, I would like to write functional tests for a controller class.

This is the signature of my controller class with a action I would like to test for example.

```
class MyController @Inject()(implicit context: ExecutionContext, val messagesApi: MessagesApi, val dao: Dao) extends Controller with I18nSupport {

    def getMyData = Action.async { implicit request =>
        dao.getMyData map { myData => 
            Ok(views.html.render(myData))
        }.recover {
            // recover.
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Dao class that is used in my controller's action :

```
import play.api.Configuration

class Dao @Inject()(val ws: WSClient, val configuration: Configuration) {

    val myConfigData: List[MyConfigData] = { ... }  // Get data from configuration

    def getMyData(): Future[List[MyData]] = {
        // use myConfigData and call web service (ws) to get some data
    }
}
```

I would like to test my controller's action using different configuration in my Dao class.
I manage to do it and my test class is working but I would like some advices to improve the code.

```
package controllers

import play.core.server.Server
import org.scalatest._
import Inspectors._
import org.scalatestplus.play._
import play.api.routing.sird._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.Play
import play.api.test._
import play.api.i18n.MessagesApi
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.test.Helpers.{ OK, status, contentAsString }
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures
import scala.concurrent.Future

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import dao.{ Dao }

import akka.util.Timeout

class MyControllerFunctionalSpec extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite with ScalaFutures {

    implicit val messagesApi = app.injector.instanceOf[MessagesApi]
    implicit val ec = app.injector.instanceOf[ExecutionContext]
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

    trait OneConfig {
        val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(""" my config """)
    }


    trait AnotherConfig {
        val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(""" my other config """)
    }

    "MyController" should {
        "get some data" in new OneConfig {
            Server.withRouter() {
                case GET(p"/url1/some/data") => Action {
                    Results.Ok(Json.arr(Json.obj("name" -> "data1")))
                }
            } { implicit port =>
                WsTestClient.withClient { client =>
                    implicit val dao = new Dao(client, Configuration(config))
                    val myController = new MyController()
                    val result = myController.getMyData(FakeRequest())
                    status(result) must equal(OK)
                    //println(contentAsString(result))
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is working like this but I was guided by compilation error and by fixing them to get it to work.

I would like help or advices to do it the right way.
Any advice welcome.

Comment: It looks more like unit tests to me. I think there is no need to extends OneAppPerSuite. You can mock all the dependencies of the controller class using some mocking framework and manually create the controller with all the dependencies passed in to constructor. You shouldn't test `Dao` (what you are actually doing) in controller tests.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I followed them, and created a test class for the controller and mock the dependencies, and created a class test class for Dao.  Yet it is still not clear for me how to write functional tests then.